# three.js let the camera look to the outside not to the center

Tags: three.js

I am a total beginner with three.js. I have a scene in three.js where a camera is inside a cube which is a room with paintings on the wall.
https://galerie-bernhardt.de/3d/files/

My Problem is, that I can not get closer to the walls of this room. I think this is because the closest point the camera can get is the center of the room. This Problem might be solved if I can rotate the direction of the camera from looking to the center to looking to the outside [What I want to do...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3o90.jpg)

The left scene is like I think the camera is working now, the second is what I want to achieve. I have tried many things, but can not figure out how to rotate the camera.

```
import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {

    const container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20 );
    camera.position.set(0,0,0);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( './' );
    loader.load( 'test_11.glb', function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );

        render();

    } );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
    controls.minDistance = 0;
    controls.maxDistance = 2.5;
    controls.minPolarAngle = 1.2;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = 2;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 8;
    controls.enableDamping = false;
    controls.target.set( 0, 0, - 0.2 );
    controls.update();

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code. I see the issue that you can't get close enough to the paintings, but we can't help you with a solution without showing the *relevant* code. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What prevents you from going past the center and yet pointing in the same direction?

Comment: OK, I posted the code...

@dcromley: I can not use negative Values for the minDistance. Thats why I can not go past the center. Or is there a possibility?

Comment: I am not familiar with "controls", sorry.  I had a camera that had negative  position z, and the lookAt was more negative z.  No problem.